# Where does hadoop store hbase data? Is there a physical path of the hbase data?

Tags: hbase

Where does hadoop store hbase data? Is there a physical path of the hbase data?
I want to using sqoop to export hbase data to MS sql. I need to specify the parameter export-dir. But I can't find the dir of the hbase data. Someone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBase table data is stored under $base_dir/data/data/$schema_name/$tablename
However, you can cannot copy **random** sqoop data under these folders. HBase stores data in **HFile** format. 
 
You will either need to write data into HFiles. Or you can use use hbase api to write data to HBase tables.
More info about bulk loading data to HBase can be found on http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.bulk.load